XPath Selector in Puppeteer 22.x
I have read the newest Puppeteer v22.x documentation about XPath, still don't know how to use XPath in Puppeteer 22.x.
I want to click an element containing the text 'Next'. Here the HTML that has the 'Next' button:
<div class="bla bla bla" role="button" tabindex="0">Next</div>

Here the behavior that I've analyzed:

The class value is not static. It will be randomly generated on every request or page refresh.
I can't use the role="button" as the indicator for the button, because in that page there are many tags using role="button" in their attributes.

Here is what I've tried:
await page.waitForSelector("xpath/div[@role='button' and text()='Next']");

await page.waitForSelector("//div[@role='button' and text()='Next']");


It is await page.waitForSelector("xpath///div[@role='button' and text()='Next']"); or await page.waitForSelector("::-p-xpath(//div[@role='button' and text()='Next'])");

When you're using XPath, you generally want to prefix the expression with // to dive deeply into the HTML tree:
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^22.7.1

const html = `<div class="bla bla bla" role="button" tabindex="0">Next</div>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const el = await page.waitForSelector(
    "xpath///div[@role='button' and text()='Next']"
  );
  console.log(await el.evaluate(el => el.textContent)); // => Next
  await el.click();
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

I'd also use normalize-space() rather than text() to handle the presence of whitespace.
Better yet, use a p-selector along with CSS: '[role="button"]::-p-text(Next)' instead of XPath (although this would be a substring text match, which may not work for your use case).
See also:

How can I get an element by xpath?
How do you click on an element with text in Puppeteer?


const el = await page.waitForSelector("::p-xpath(///div[@role='button' and text()='Next'])");
await el.click();

you can do this for selecting element with xpath for puppeteer latest version
Reference : https://pptr.dev/guides/page-interactions/#xpath-selectors--p-xpath
